# Positive lookahead doesn't match Arabic text

Tags: php, regex, pcre, arabic-support, positive-lookahead

Regex doesn't match Arabic text when using lookahead assertion

I am  trying to split the text:

> شكرا لك على المشاركة في هذه الدراسة. هذا الاستبيان يطلب معلومات عن:

stored in

```
$sentences = "شكرا لك على المشاركة في هذه الدراسة. هذا الاستبيان يطلب معلومات عن:";
```

with regex:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=\.)\s+(?=\p{IsArabic}+)/";
```

in function

```
preg_split($pattern, $sentences);
```

The regex doesn't match. It does match if I remove the lookahead assertion.

Why does that happen? What could be a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix it by using the `\p{Arabic}` Unicode property class (see [supported names here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)) and adding `u` modifier to the regex. Note that `+` quantifier after `\p{Arabic}` is redundant.

Use

```
$sentences = "شكرا لك على المشاركة في هذه الدراسة. هذا الاستبيان يطلب معلومات عن:";
$pattern = "/(?<=\.)\s+(?=\p{Arabic})/u";
print_r(preg_split($pattern, $sentences));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => شكرا لك على المشاركة في هذه الدراسة.
    [1] => هذا الاستبيان يطلب معلومات عن:
)
```